# How to use MTKTextureLoader newTextureWithContentsOfURL to retrieve an image from the web?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit, mtktextureloader

Is it possible to use `MTKTextureLoader.newTextureWithContentsOfURL` to retrieve an image from the web (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwPfY.jpg?s=48&g=1)? I tried but I didn't succeed, so maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `-newTextureWithContentsOfURL:...` methods are intended for use with file URLs, not Web URLS.

If you want to load an image from the Internet, you should use `NSURLSession` and `NSURLDataTask` to download the image contents first (asynchronously), and then use `MTKTextureLoader`'s `-newTextureWithData:options:error:` method or its asynchronous counterpart to create a `MTLTexture`.